# Plotting hidden variable/parameter

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I would like to plot some parametric plots as a function of a 0-1 variable.
I can easily set up `x=linspace(0,1)` and define functions `a(x)`, `b(x)`, and `plot(a,b)`.

What I would like to do, however, is indicated in the plotted diagrams the value of my original `x` parameter.  I would guess there is a function to do so, although I haven't found it yet.  Optionally, I could also do a color gradient with a bar along each trace for my 0-1.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You could easily add progress markers by using plotting options for markers, `'o'` for example. To tag specific points you could use the `text` function.

Comment: AFAIK there is no directly way to do this, but you can get the indexes of the values of x where you want the markers, using something like `ismember` and then use those indexes to plot the corresponding values of a and b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good news! You can do all sort of things quite easily, let's start with defining some data:

```
x = linspace(0,1);
a = sin(5.*x);
b = cos(6.*x);
```

Now, we make a simple plot:

```
plot(x,a,'-o',x,b,'^')
```

The `'-o'` means the first series of data (`a`) will be plotted as line with circle markers, the `'^'` means the second series of data (`b`) will be plotted with no line, just triangles. You can find [all options here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html?searchHighlight=plot#inputarg_LineSpec).
Next, we call:

```
text(x(50)+0.03,a(50),sprintf('x = %0.3f',x(50)),'FontSize',14)
text(x(30)+0.03,b(30),sprintf('x = %0.3f',x(30)),'FontSize',14)
```

the [`text`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html) command print text at specific coordinates on the figure. For example, the first line will print in (x(30)+0.03,a(30)) the text "x = 0.495". The text string is formatted with another function [`sprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html), but you can just write simple text in single quote marks (`'`).
Finally, we can add [`legend`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/legend.html) by:

```
legend({'sin(5x)','cos(6x)'},'FontSize',16,'Location','SouthWest')
```

note that the text strings are in a cell array.

And we get the result:

[image: Plot demo]

That's the kind of stuff you have been looking for?

Comment: Nice font! :D What is it?

Comment: The font is "Helvetica", it's the default in my computer.

Comment: Indeed!, I did figure it out before seeing this, but then again, this was the way to do it!